# Creating Electron executable from Angular local web application

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, electron

I've this problem: I wanted to create a desktop app with a executable file, but i can't do it right, whatever i try. I successfully created the executable with electron-packager, i builted the app into the dist folder with those four minimized files (main, styles, runtime and polyfills) and the index.html, but when I run the executable the only thing I see is white screen.

I was thinking about two ways of handling this:

1. starting the app on localhost:4200 in... some way, exactly when I run the executable, but I don't know how to do it
2. reading those files in the dist folder, but i keep getting errors that say "to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" at row 1 of each file

I'll leave here the three files that I believe are most important in this problem.

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "library-frontend": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/library-frontend",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "3MB",
                  "maximumError": "5MB"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "library-frontend:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "library-frontend:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "library-frontend:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "library-frontend",
  "version": "1.0.4",
  "main": "electron.main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "serve": "ng serve",
    "start": "concurrently \"ng serve\" \"npm run electron\"",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "electron": "electron ./electron.main",
    "electron-build": "ng build && electron ./electron.main",
    "electron-win": "electron-packager . --platform=win32"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^16.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^16.0.1",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^16.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^16.0.2",
    "node-windows": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.5.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.0.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.16",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "concurrently": "^8.0.1",
    "electron": "^24.0.0",
    "electron-packager": "^17.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4"
  }
}
```

electron.main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');

let win;

const createWindow = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        win = new BrowserWindow({
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            icon: './src/favicon.ico'
        });

        const appUrl = url.pathToFileURL(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/library-frontend/index.html')).toString();
        win.loadURL(appUrl);

        win.on('closed', () => {
            win = null;
        });
    }, 10000);
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (win === null) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

These files are all in the root of the project, the same level as src folder, which contains index.html and all other components.

The first solution I wrote before is probably wrong, but what I want is exactly what happens when I run my "npm run start" command, which runs concurrently `ng serve` and `npm run electron`

Comment: trying to start the packaged app with localhost:4200 web server is a really bad idea. Don't do that. Your issue is probably that the path you create is wrong. add asar:false to packager config and check what files are packaged in your resources/app folder in the end result. and do some console.log() magic to check if the path you create is correct.  to switch between production and  development url for the browserwindow, just use app.isPackaged bool.

Comment: @Welcor thanks for your answer. Where exactly can I add asar:false? Also, tecnhically the path is correct, but I never checked with console.log(). Where should I put it to check?

Comment: that depends on the tool you use for packaging. i think asar:false is a direct setting of electron-packager, but i only used electron-forge and electron-builder so far. No idea where electron-package expects that option to be set. yeah console.log might be a bit tricky.. because you dont see the log from main process. hm. or you could use fs.writeFile() or what it is called and write it to a file instead

Comment: if you plan to keep using electron-packager maybe using electron-forge is a solution for you. it runs electron-packager internally and is the official way for setting up an electron project right now. but it requires additional setup too though which may result in new issues.